# C pthreads run in portions

Tags: c, concurrency, pthreads

I have list with 1000-10000 jobs. It's stored in simple char array. I need to finish work on the list as fast as i can.

I want to run 10 threads at any time. How i have to run new thread immediately (or almost immediately) after previous thread is done?

```
#define THREADS_LIMIT 10
const char * const jobs[]= { "data1", .... }
...
for (i = 0; i < THREADS_LIMIT; ++i)
{
// run first 10 threads
}
```

How can i start thread after previous is done ? I can run 10 threads, then wait until ALL of the is done, and then run next 10. But is there more efficient way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't stop any threads. Simply have each thread move on to the next job instead of destroying it and creating a new one; they terminate when no more work remains. Now your main routine just starts THREAD_LIMIT threads, then `pthread_join`s them all.

Comment: @twoface88 You should tell the threads which jobs they are doing.

Comment: @twoface88, make sure that doesn't happen. You could have a 'next job' counter protected by a lock, for example. When a thread needs a job, it takes the lock, reads the counter into a local variable, increments it, drops the lock, then gets to work.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you might consider is to have a threadsafe queue of jobs that each thread can pull work from until there is no more work left.  Then start up however many threads is appropriate and let them all work until there are no more jobs. Something like:

```
#define THREADS_LIMIT 10

static pthread_mutex_t job_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static const char * const jobs[]= { "data1", .... };

char const* get_job(void) 
{
    pthread_mutex_lock( &job_mutex);

    static char const* next_job = jobs;
    static char const* jobs_end = jobs + (sizeof(jobs)/sizeof(jobs[0]));

    char const* result = NULL;

    if (next_job != jobs_end) {
        result = next_job++;
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock( &job_mutex);

    return result;
}



...
for (i = 0; i < THREADS_LIMIT; ++i)
{
// run first 10 threads
}


void* thread_fun( void* arg)
{
    for (char const* my_job = get_job(); my_job != NULL; my_job = get_job()) {
        // work on the job *my_job
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that if your jobs are CPU intensive, you should probably limit the number of them you spin up to the number of CPU cores the machine has. More than that and they'll fight each other for CPU time.

However, if you want the flexibility of having the jobs queue dynamic (so jobs can be added to the queue while threads are working jobs), the complexity grows. It grows only a little bit to keep the add/remove logic thread safe. But it grow quite a bit more in order to make sure that there are still threads around to process the job queue - for example, you have to make sure there are no race conditions where you think there's still one or more threads around to process the queue, but those threads are actually just about to end themselves without checking the job queue again.
And of course, at the cost a a bit more complexity in how your jobs are stored, you can extend this so that the jobs queue can have items added to it

Comment: I realise it's just sample code but you should _always_ check return code from mutex functions, it's better to fail immediately than generate incorrect results (and they _can_ fail). And you may want to return the result from `get_job` :-)

Comment: Right on both counts. I fixed the return from `get_job()`; I'll leave the error handling as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want a thread pool, you don't want to be starting and stopping threads for each task.

The major design issue is how you are distributing the tasks to the pool, such matters can be simplified with a middleware package like [0mq](http://zero.mq) to perform lockless IPC between the scheduler and workers.

If the list of jobs is hard coded then you can statically split the work load and say give each thread an index into the job queue and have them iterate through until complete.

Comment: You don't need a thread pool if the thread count is a constant, it just introduces unnecessary complexity. Just start the threads you need and farm out the work to them one at a time.

Comment: Fair enough. I was thinking more of the dynamic ones where the number of threads can expand and contract based on workload, so apologies for misunderstanding your intent.

Answer (score 0):

The best way (in my opinion) is to create a queue holding the jobs and then start up ten threads which simply read the next job from the queue and process it.

This has the advantage of minimal thread creation/destruction overhead and automatic balancing of workloads among the threads. By that, I mean threads which get quick jobs automatically get more jobs to work on.

Then, at the end of those 10,000 jobs, you place 10 shutdown jobs which will cause the worker thread to exit, then you wait on them.

The whole scheme looks like this:

```
main thread:
    create a queue
    do ten times:
        start a worker thread
    do ten thousand times:
        add normal job to queue
    do ten times:
        add shutdown job to queue
    wait for all workers to finish
    exit

worker thread:
    while true:
        get job from queue
        if job is shutdown job:
            exit
        process job
```

Obviously, access to the queue needs to be protected with a mutex to avoid race conditions.

---

One thing you need to keep in mind though. If the tasks are CPU-intensive, you're not going to get any real benefit from having more threads than available execution unit (CPUs or cores or whatever).

For example, if you only have one core, the fastest way to do what you want is to simply not use threads at all. Using threads on a CPU-intensive task like that will actually probably be *slower* since you're introducing the overhead of task switching.

Comment: At least in the desktop / server arenas, having only one core is rapidly becoming a minor corner-case.

Comment: @caf, that was an example. Similarly it does no good to run 10 CPU-bound threads on an quad-core grunt machine. Four would be the upper limit of usefulness there.